# Ajax/jquery won't update php session

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I can't get it to update my php session

```
    $.ajax({
type:'POST',
url: 'checkoutSession.php',
data: $('leveringsnavn').serialize(),
}).complete(function(data){
    alert(data.responseText);
```

});

checkoutSession.php

```
<?php
session_start();
ECHO "<script> alert('HAHAHHAHHAHA1');</script>";
if (isset($_POST['fakturaNavn'])) {
       ECHO "<script> alert('HAHAHHAHHAHA2');</script>";
        $_SESSION['kundeOplysninger'][] = array("fakturaNavn" => $_POST['fakturaNavn']);

        ECHO "<script> alert('HAHAHHAHHAHA3');</script>";
}
```

I comes with the hahahahaha1, alert box, but not the second or 3'th ..

Can anybody help me solve this problem ?

Comment: is `leveringsnavn` a form id? If so then change `$('leveringsnavn')` to `$('#leveringsnavn')`

Comment: yes it is the form id, i have tried that too.. not helping ..

Comment: done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($_POST)` to see what you're receiving? most likely you DON'T have a `fakturaNavn` field, which means the if() fails and skips the rest of the code.

Comment: haha ! i had called the form name="leveringsnavn" .. instead of id="leveringsnavn.. danm!! changed that and now working ..

Comment: haha .. so can i use the session on the current page, like update some <p> or <div>.. without refresh the page..

Comment: haha glad it worked out